# Divergence theorem: compute triple integral over a paraboloid between two planes

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, volume, divergence-theorem

> Let $S$ be the surface of equation $z=x^2 + y^2$, which is between the planes $z=1$ and $z=x+y+3$. Let $F = (x^2,y,z)$. Compute the flux of $F$ across $S$

I think I should use divergence theorem, hence I only need to compute $$\int \int \int_V \operatorname{div}(F)dxdydz$$ but I don't know how to describe the volume enclosed by $S$.

I'd like to integrate this way:

$$\int \int_{D} \Big[\int_{1}^{x+y+3}2x + 2 dz\Big] dxdy$$

But I don't know how to define the domain $D$ where the coordinates $x$ and $y$ are. I think I should the two conditions on the planes, but I can't. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are applying divergence theorem, you will have to close the  surface with disks in planes $z=1$ and $z = x+y+3$. You will need to separately calculate flux through the disks and subtract from the flux through the closed surface.

Now good thing is that within the paraboloid domain, plane $z = x + y + 3$ is throughout above plane $z=1$. Also note that the intersection of the given circular paraboloid and the given plane can be seen in $XY$ plane as -

$x^2+y^2 = x + y + 3 \implies (x-0.5)^2 + (y-0.5)^2 = 3.5$

So at the minimum, it makes sense to use cylindrical coordinates with

$x = 0.5 + r \cos \theta, y = 0.5 + r \sin\theta, 0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{3.5}$

$1 \leq z \leq 4 + 0.5 \cos\theta + 0.5 \sin\theta, \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

So the integral to find flux becomes

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt {3.5}} \int_1^{4+r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta} r(3+ 2r\cos\theta) \ dz \ dr \ d\theta$

Now please find flux through disks at $z=1$ and $z=x+y+3$ and subtract from the above. That should give you the flux through paraboloid surface.

---

Just as a side note: if you want to simplify the limits of integration further, you can in fact rotate the paraboloid by $\frac{\pi}{4}$. There is no change to Jacobian just like in the first case. It will simplify the equation of the plane $z = x + y + 3$.

$x = 0.5 + r \cos (\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta), y = 0.5 + r \sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta), 0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{3.5}$

Equation of plane becomes $z = x+y+3 = 4 + r \cos(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta) + r \sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + \theta) = 4 + r \sqrt2 \cos\theta$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having difficulties in computing thee flux across $z=x+y+3$. What I did is $\int \int_DF \cdot n dS$ where $D$ is the bottom disk. Can I parametrize it with polars in this way? $\rho \in (0,3.5)$ and $\theta \in (0,2 \pi)$?

Comment: Disk at $z=x+y+3$ is not the bottom disk but the top disk. $z=1$ has the bottom disk. For disk in $z = x + y + 3$, the outward normal vector is $\vec{n} = (-1, -1, 1)$. The bounds of $r$ and $\theta$ are correct. Make sure to substitute $x = 0.5 + r \cos\theta, y = 0.5 + r \sin\theta, z = 4 + 0.5 \cos\theta + 0,5 \sin\theta$ in the vector field.

Comment: Yes sorry, I made a mistake while writing it. Btw, I can't find your normal vector $n$. You just computed the external product between $\partial_\rho $ and $\partial_\theta$, right?

Comment: Normal vector to a plane $ax+by+cz=d$ is $(a, b, c)$, right? We are in plane $z = x + y + 3$. Hence the normal vector. We just make sure $z$ is positive because we want outward normal vector. For the bottom disk, _outward_ normal vector is $(0, 0, -1)$.

Comment: Clear, thanks. But shouldn't I obtain the same result by just computing the exterior product of the partials? @MathLover

Comment: It is not necessary for a plane but if you want to do that, represent the plane as $(x, y, x + y + 3)$. Then do $\partial_x \times \partial_y$ and you will get the same result.

Comment: You can also do $\partial_r \times \partial_{\theta}$ and you will get the same result except that instead of $(-1, -1, 1)$, you will get $(-r, -r, r)$. $r$ is the Jacobian we otherwise plug in when converting from $dx \ dy$ to $dr \ d\theta$.

Comment: Clear, I think you should write $3 + r \cos(\theta) + r \sin(\theta)$ as upper coordinate of integration in the $z$ variable, right?

Comment: We have $x = 0.5 + r \cos \theta, y = 0.5 + r \sin\theta$ so $x+y+3$ will be $4 + ...$.

Comment: oh, my... I feel ashamed, thanks :-)